# How can I create a PasteButton that changes its "contents" dynamically?

Tags: dynamic, scoping, units, inputfield, palettes

I'm trying to make a units palette to help with my various engineering courses. I thought about creating a "meta-palette" of sorts, maybe one that changes on the fly, or one where I can create all the buttons, arrange them on a grid and then export as a palette.

The first major hurdle I encountered and the issue at hand is that I can't for the life of me find a way to make the button's content "stick". Either the pasted content is left unevaluated, or it changes along with the `InputField` or just plain out throws an error. I have tried with and without many, if not all, combinations of `Dynamic` and non-`Dynamic` versions of `Module`, `Setting`, `Evaluate`, `Defer`, and more.

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
Quantity; Module[{QN = {list, of, all units}
 DynamicModule[{U = "", N = ""}, 
  Grid@{{"Button:", 
     Quiet[PasteButton[Dynamic@N, Quantity[None, U (*Herein lies the issue*)]]]}, {"Label:", 
     InputField[Dynamic@N, String, 
      ContinuousAction -> True]}, {"Unit:", 
     InputField[Dynamic@U, String, ContinuousAction -> True, 
      FieldCompletionFunction ->  
          Select[QN, 
           StringContainsQ[#, IgnoreCase -> True]] &)]}}]]
```

I trimmed some unnecessary strings to reduce bulk.

The intended behavior of that button is to input the unit typed in the bottom text box. After this I might want to duplicate the button as a "static" one so that it can be reused later, but I think that solving this issue would simplify that goal.

I hope you guys can help me figure this one out, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `Button` the `PastButton` does not have `HoldRest` attribute. You can rewrite it then:

```
Button[Dynamic@N, NotebookApply[InputNotebook[], Quantity[None, U ]] ]
```

Does it fit your needs?

Comment: It does work, however it leaves the pasted data unevaluated, I fixed it by modifying it to:
`Button[Dynamic@N, 
 NotebookApply[InputNotebook[], Quantity[None, U], All]; 
 SelectionEvaluate@InputNotebook[]]`. I has a bit of a glitchy behavior if clicked while the cursor is set outside a cell, but I think I can live with that.

Comment: Also, I just tried to convert it to a palette and it doesn't work; either I can't type in the `InputField`s or it pastes the data into the palette's fields, instead of the working notebook.
I'll try to look for an answer or, if needed, open a new question.

Comment: @juanmanuel i fixed what you asked for. Please describe what is your end goal in detail and what exactly does not work.

Comment: You can ignore my second comment.
What I wanted to paste is not just the expression `Quantity[None,U]` but the result as if you evaluated it in place, so in the notebook it looks like just `kg`, for example. That's what the first comment's tweak achieves.